# Git push does nothing with Google Code repo as remote

Tags: git, push, google-code

I have a git project at Google Code.
https://code.google.com/p/jawabot/

I did some commits to `master` branch. They're fine, visible in `git log`.
Now when I do `git push`, I get "

```
$ git push
Password: 
Everything up-to-date
```

And sometimes:

```
$ git push
Password: 
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing    https://dynawest@code.google.com/p/jawabot//info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

*Update:*

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://dynawest@code.google.com/p/jawabot/ (fetch)
origin  https://dynawest@code.google.com/p/jawabot/ (push)
```

What's wrong? Me or Google? (I'm git newbie.)

If someone was so kind and tried to push something there, I'd be glad (I assume I will be able to revert such change).

**Update:**

Based on answers, I tried  (git:// url guessed):

```
$ git remote add gc git@code.google.com:jawabot/jawabot.git
$ git remote -v
gc      git@code.google.com:jawabot/jawabot.git (fetch)
gc      git@code.google.com:jawabot/jawabot.git (push)
origin  https://dynawest@code.google.com/p/jawabot/ (fetch)
origin  https://dynawest@code.google.com/p/jawabot/ (push)
ondra@ondra-doma:/mnt/ssd1/_projekty/JawaBot-2.0-git$ git push gc

ssh: connect to host code.google.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: I wonder why would anyone put -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is answered in the FAQ: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GitFAQ

Both why just a `git push` would not work and also on supporting `https` only and not other protocols.

> **Why does Git refuse to push, saying "everything up to date"?**
>
> git push  with no additional arguments only pushes branches
>   that exist in the remote already. If the remote repository is empty,
>   nothing will be pushed. In this case, explicitly specify a branch to
>   push, e.g. git push  master.
>
> **Can I access my repository over
>   git:// or ssh:// instead of https:// ?**
>
> In order to take advantage of the advanced scalability and
>   load-balancing features of Google's production servers, we are only
>   able to accept incoming HTTP connections. We have no plans to support
>   protocols other than the Git Smart HTTP protocol introduced in v1.6.6.
>
> We do support both anonymous (read-only) and authenticated
>   (read/write) access over HTTPS.

Answer (score 6):

The steps for you would be . Did you forget 1

```
git add <files>
git commit -m 'message'
git push origin master
```

Comment: Nope, as I said, commits are in `git log`.

Comment: In the end it turned out that I forgot part of step 3 :)

Comment: Happens the first time -- everyone fumbles :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved - It was missing the branch specification...

```
$ git push origin master
Password: 
Counting objects: 3724, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2762/2762), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3724/3724), 1.21 MiB | 136 KiB/s, done.
Total 3724 (delta 1669), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Scanning pack: 100% (3724/3724), done.
remote: Storing objects: 100% (3724/3724), done.
remote: Processing commits: 100% (196/196), done.
To https://dynawest@code.google.com/p/jawabot/
 * [new branch]      master -> master
ondra@ondra-doma:/mnt/ssd1/_projekty/JawaBot-2.0-git$
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially what you might want to try doing is instead of using the https address, to use the git protocol, like git://git.foo.